# Views show fields is set, but only "Content" options are available to select - why?

Tags: views

Simple question. I thought I knew views, but right now I'm stuck. All I want is a view with the body field of a certain content type.

I have "Fields" selected:

[image]

But when I go to add a field, my options are severely limited:

[image]

(There is no such thing as a "Content: Body" option to select.)

What happened to the rest of the categories in the Filter dropdown? I'm missing something obvious here...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Content: Body` field should be there as long as it exists in the content type.

A couple things you can try in this order:

1. Ensure all permissions are set properly
2. Flush all caches
3. Flush the views cache at `/admin/structure/views/settings/advanced`
4. Disable views cache just to see if that's an issue
5. Update Views

Here's a [current issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1954348) of the problem

Comment: I had to disable views data caching (just flushing didn't work). I have seen other manifestations of this cache issue around the site (especially since we started working with solr for some reason) but hadn't connected the dots. Good to know about this issue; I had not seen it yet. Thanks.